# ValueError: Shapes (32, 1) and (32, 2) are incompatible

Tags: python

Hi Everyone I'm doing sentiment analysis project with lstm model
After Preprocessing the data.

I'm doing pad sequences to processed text and label encoding to polarity

After that, my shapes are:

```
(7136, 65) (7136,)
(1784, 65) (1784,)
```

My code for lstm model is

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(2000, 32, input_length=max_review_length))

model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(176, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))

model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),epochs = 5, batch_size=32, verbose = 'auto')
```

But I'm getting value error with the shape
Please help me and suggest me 
I'm new to these concepts
Hoping to hear positive response

Comment: Could you share the value of max_review_length?

Answer (score 0):

So... the binary_crossentropy expects a binary classification problem. You could either use categorical_crossentropy instead (with a one-hot labelling), but I think for you setting

```
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

instead of

```
model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
```

should do the trick.